# How to say "No" to Relocation for training purpose?

Tags: interviewing, relocation

I just gave an interview to the company and they are happy with my performance and they want me to hire. They said they will place in the place which I want but want me to relocate to the Training place for first two months. But it would be difficult for me to relocate for 2 months as I will be getting married next month.

How can I tell him about my problem and ask him to give me the training in my base location.

Comment: Tell them you have the wedding planned and ask whether the training can be delayed until after that, or if there's another solution. (If training was available at your base location they probably wouldn't be paying you to travel...)

Answer (score 2):

You do this through a process called **negotiation**.

In this, you state what you would like and what you are willing to do and they state what they would like and what they are willing to do. Each party then adjusts their position in order to see if there is a mutually satisfactory outcome (or deal); if there isn't then the parties go their separate ways.

It seems that they have stated their position:

> they will place in the place which I want but want me to relocate to the Training place for first two months

And your position (which you have not communicated to them) is:

> it would be difficult for me to relocate for 2 months as I will be getting married next month

As it stands, your Best Alternative to a Negotiated Agreement (BATNA) is:

1. Take the job and disrupt your marriage
2. Not take the job

**You need to tell them what you are telling us and find out if what you are proposing is even possible for the company**.

When you know all of their relevant information and they know all yours it may be that a deal can be reached.